# How can I change my birthday information on my Stack Overflow user profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

I signed up using GitHub account, but I don't know how to change the birthday information on my Stack Overflow user profile.

I hope it is easy to change my birthday information on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow has a birthday field anymore. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340427